# AngularJS Service Test (Jasmine/Karma) - Error: Unexpected request: GET

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm currently trying to test an AngularJS service I've written using Karma and Jasmine. However, I'm currently running into an issue with `$httpBackend` and I cannot get around it.  Here's my service and test:

Service:

```
export default angular.module("api:events", [])
.factory("Events", ($http) => {
    let api = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
    let Events = {};

    Events.query = (params) => {
        return $http.get(`${api}/events`, {params: params}).then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        });
    };

    Events.get = (params) => {
        return $http.get(`${api}/events/` + params.id).then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        });
    };

    return Events;
});
```

Test:

```
describe("api:events", () => {
    let EventsFactory, $scope, http;

    beforeEach(module("app"));

    beforeEach(inject((_Events_, $rootScope, $httpBackend) => {
        EventsFactory = _Events_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        http = $httpBackend;
    }));


    it("should return an object", () => {
        let data = {};
        let url = "http://localhost:5000/api/events/:id";
        let response = { id: "12345" };

        http.whenGET(url).respond(200, response);

        data = EventsFactory.get({ id: "1"});

        expect(data).not.toEqual("12345");

        http.flush();

        expect(data).toEqual("12345");

        http.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        http.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
});
```

And the error I'm receiving (due to `http.flush()`):

```
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) api:events test FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:5000/api/events/1
    No more request expected
```

If I log data after `data = EventsFactory.get({ id: "1"});` I get `Object{$$state: Object{status: 0}}`.

I've also tried calling my service like this with similar results:

```
EventsFactory.get({ id: "1"}).then((result) => {
    data = result;
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe the reason is that the URL given to `whenXXX()` is literal, i.e. the `:id` part will be used as is in the "expectation". I believe changing to `url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/events/1'` will correct the problem.

Comment: Nikos, that's it! That's extremely frustrating. Thanks for your help though! If you can post that as an answer I'll mark yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that URLs given to the `whenXXX()` and `expectXXX()` methods of the `$http` mocks have to be literal. One could intuitevely expect that URLs with parameters (e.g. the `:id` in the code from the question) will work, but that is not the case. So to correct the error, just replace:

```
let url = "http://localhost:5000/api/events/:id";
```

with:

```
let url = "http://localhost:5000/api/events/1"; // `1` is the literal id
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#verifyNoOutstandingExpectation) for `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` and `verifyNoOutstandingRequest()`.

It says:

> Verifies that all of the requests defined via the expect api were made.

The key words there are "expect api". You are not using the "expect" API, you're using then "when" API. You shouldn't be calling either of these methods at the end of your test when using the "when" API.

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#request-expectations-vs-backend-definitions) describes the differences between the "expect" and "when" API.

Comment: That makes sense. However, even if I remove those two lines I still hit the same error.